# OpenCV stopped to work for no reason at all

Tags: opencv, libraries, javacv

I've made an application in Java that is using OpenCV (javaCV) libraries in NetBeans IDE. All was working fine for about 0.5 year and yesterday for no reason it stopped to connect to the openCV libraries (It looks like OpenCV isn't configured well anymore). Strangest thing is that 3 copies of this program were in usage by my friends (On Windows 8, Windows XP and Mac OS X)and all of them have now this same connection to library error. This application isn't connected to internet in any way, also I never made any update on it so I find it very strange that every single copy stopped to work :(

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_highgui in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:79)
at Program.Core.Find(Core.java:64)
at Program.Core.FindActionPerformed(Core.java:516)
at Program.Core.access$000(Core.java:25)
at Program.Core$1.actionPerformed(Core.java:414)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
      Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/2x/p7_dz5n931d4bmbbjw68d5z00000gn/T/javacpp1445446196924953000/libjniopencv_highgui.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/2x/p7_dz5n931d4bmbbjw68d5z00000gn/T/javacpp1445446196924953000/libjniopencv_highgui.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
        Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2x/p7_dz5n931d4bmbbjw68d5z00000gn/T/javacpp1445446196924953000/libjniopencv_highgui.dylib
                Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/folders/2x/p7_dz5n931d4bmbbjw68d5z00000gn/T/javacpp1445446196924953000/./libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib: malformed mach-o image: load command #22 length (0) too small in /private/var/folders/2x/p7_dz5n931d4bmbbjw68d5z00000gn/T/javacpp1445446196924953000/./libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:700)
... 43 more
       Java Result: 128
      BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: I do not know about java and opencv. but after 6 months, is not it normal that you have upgraded your java VM or re-install operating system so you lost environment variables or or or...?

Comment: This has nothing to do with opencv. it doesnt change unless you change it